# Can you have an empty XML element with use="required"

Tags: xml, xsd

I imagine this is a simple question to answer but using the XSD line below, is the XML line below valid or not?

XSD

```
<xsd:element name="Something" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>
```

XML

```
<Something />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use="required" applies to attributes not elements.
By default an element is required (minOccurs defaults to 1).
If you want to change this set minOccurs/maxOccurs.

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2017 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="d">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="myAttribute" type="xs:int" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```